# Get one-to-many relationships using LINQ and stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql, linq

I have 2 tables:

```
tbl_Orders
id       OrderN        DateAdd
1        77-65        01.01.2011
2        77-73        24.01.2011
3        77-82        13.01.2011
4        77-86        15.01.2011
5        77-89        11.01.2011


tbl_OrdersList
id       OrderId        ItemId
1        1              23
2        1              32
3        3              33
4        5              45 
5        5              48
```

There is orders in tbl_Orders and purchase in this orders in tbl_OrdersList.
So, there are 5 orders in system:

1. Order1 (id=1) = 2 purchase (itemsId=23,32)
2. Order2 (id=2) - empty
3. Order3 (id=3) = 1 purchase (itemsId=33)
4. Order4 (id=4) - empty
5. Order5 (id=5) = 2 purchase (itemsId=45,48)

So, i use LINQ2Sql and there i'd like **to execute stored procedure, not generated by LINQ sql code**.

How is it better to write this stored procedure? Is there a few usp (first for Orders, second for OrdersList)?

How is it better to **make relationships** after i execute my usp (for example, using generated classes and LINQ generated code, i could make something like this:

```
// Orders - get orders from tbl using dataContext and tbl_Orders
foreach(var order in Orders){
    foreach(var orderlist in order.OrdersList) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Answer of my question was attribute 'Return type' in properties window, when u've already drag usp to dbml methods and click on it. By default, there is auto-generated type, but i can change it to 'Order' type.

Answer (score 0):

Linq2Sql is Linq's weakest link.  The SQL it generates is decent for simple cases, but often degenerates when you add the final touches to the code.  Degeneration can be 1000x or far worse.  It's a honey trap: it starts out great and then becomes a thick mess when when your deadline draws neigh.

I'd get into the habit of writing stored procedures.

Comment: So. Is there something about my question? I know that usp usually better, but how i can map result into objects like Orders and Orders.OrdersList?

Comment: Add a DBML file to your project. Drag your stored procedure from server explorer to the DBML file.  This generates a DataContext with a C# function that will map your stored procedure to an object.

Comment: It will map with AutoGenerated type. I've already found a way to map return type which i need.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim q = From o In Orders, ol In OrdersList _
           where o.id Equals ol.OrderId Into ords = Group _
            From ol In ords.DefaultIfEmpty _
            Select New With {o.OrderN, o.DateAdd,ords.ItemID}
```